# Hiding output on specific columns

Tags: sql, oracle, security, database-cursor

I have written a package that has a stored procedure and a REF cursor.  I am able to now display all of the columns in my table through this cursor.  I would like to be able to insert a loop that if a certain condition is met, four of the seven columns will show four asterisks and the rest of the columns will show up with their normal data.

For example, I have a column called country.  Any time that USA appears in a record, the four columns of (empid, ss, address, dept) will need to only show **** while the rest of the columns will appear as normal.  If a country that is not USA is in a record, then all columns will show the data as normal.  I know there is a noprint function but I can't seem to figure out how to just show the asterisks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using something complicated for this, just use a `CASE` expression:

`SELECT CASE WHEN Country = 'USA' THEN '*****' Else EmpID END as EmpID`

Comment: +1, always do it in SQL first, if possible. If you can't do that, *then* look at the procedural options.

Comment: Thanks.  I need to use a stored procedure to take away direct table access from the application.  Is there a way I can use this CASE expression on the cursor?  I tried to enter it but am getting some errors.

Comment: Why don't you use a `VIEW` instead of a `CURSOR`?  Regardless, just put the `CASE` in your `SELECT` wherever it is (cursor or elsewhere)

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.  I can't use a view as that either shows a column or doesn't.  I need to hide some data, but not all within the column.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Christopher - You can use a `CASE` inside the view as well.  `CURSORS` are almost never the right solution to whatever the problem is.